# My custom value converter causes XAML validation tool to fail

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I've created a custom converter that performs converting of values based on configured mapping. It looks like below

```
public class UniversalConverter : List<ConverterItem>, IValueConverter
{
    private bool useDefaultValue;

    private object defaultValue;

    public object DefaultValue
    {
        get { return defaultValue; }
        set
        {
            defaultValue = value;
            useDefaultValue = true;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            if (Equals(item.From, value))
                return item.To;
        if (useDefaultValue)
            return DefaultValue;
        throw new ConversionException(string.Format("Value {0} can't be converted and default value is not allowed", value));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        foreach (var item in this)
            if (Equals(item.To, value))
                return item.From;
        throw new ConversionException(string.Format("Value {0} can't be converted back", value));
    }
}

public class ConverterItem
{
    public object From { get; set; }

    public object To { get; set; }
}

public class ConversionException : Exception
{
    public ConversionException() { }

    public ConversionException(string message) : base(message) { }
}
```

Sample XAML is below

```
<core:UniversalConverter x:Key="ItemCountToVisiblityConverter" DefaultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
    <core:ConverterItem To="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}">
        <core:ConverterItem.From>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        </core:ConverterItem.From>
    </core:ConverterItem>
</core:UniversalConverter>
```

Now everything builds and works fine, but if I use it XAML Visual Studio underscores the whole file with curvy blue lines and shows two kind of mistakes:

1) If converter is put into `ResourceDictionary` AND is assigned an `x:Key` attribute it shows `Missing key value on 'UniversalConverter' object`

2) If I assign `DefaultValue` property any value (e.g `{x:Null}`) the message is `XAML Node Stream: Missing EndMember for 'StuffLib.UniversalConverter.{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml}_Items' before StartMember 'StuffLib.UniversalConverter.DefaultValue'`

What is the reason for those messages? I can live with them but they hide all other compiler and ReSharper markings

Comment: Could you please post your XAML code?

Comment: You need to share full code, otherwise we can't tell where's the error

Comment: @Dominik this really makes no difference what conversion logic I use. Even if I just write `return DependecyProperty.UnsetValue` I still see this underscore

Comment: Please, show us the XAML, and the implementation of your value converter. Since you are having an issue with getting one or both of these right, it very well *might* make a difference what your code looks like. Otherwise we have only your current analysis to go on, and that is not enough -- if it were, you wouldn't be here in the first place.

Comment: That being said, if you are positively sure that both your XAML and your value converter code are correct, you could always try deleting your `bin` and `obj` folders and restarting Visual Studio. That sometimes helps; the XAML designer can be a little moody and erratic.

Comment: @stakx added full code and sample XAML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't inherit from list, just create Items property in your converter:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class UniversalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public ConverterItem[] Items { get; set; }

    public object DefaultValue { get; set; }
    //all other stuff goes here
}
```

and xaml:

```
<l:UniversalConverter x:Key="MyConverter">
  <x:Array Type="l:ConverterItem">
    <l:ConverterItem From="..." To="..." />
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it made me look the proper way. See my own answer below for details and edits. I'll award bounty in 22 hours

Comment: I still don't know why inheriting from list causes this error, but this solves my problem with NullReferenceExceptions in the designer. The code from @Demarsch in his additional answer even makes the XAML code looking the same.

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer given by @Leiro

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class UniversalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public UniversalConverter()
    {
        Items = new List<ConverterItem>();
    }

    public List<ConverterItem> Items { get; private set; } 
    //All other logic is the same
}
```

Note that this way you won't need to wrap items in collection in XAML

Resulting XAML

```
<core:UniversalConverter x:Key="ItemCountToVisiblityConverter" DefaultValue="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
    <core:ConverterItem To="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}">
        <core:ConverterItem.From>
            <system:Int32>0</system:Int32>
        </core:ConverterItem.From>
    </core:ConverterItem>
</core:UniversalConverter>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it is being used at design time but there is no data so I suspect a NullReferenceException is being thrown. Try checking for design time mode as follows at the top of the IValueConverter.Convert() method body:

```
// Check for design mode. 
if ((bool)(DesignerProperties.IsInDesignModeProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(DependencyObject)).DefaultValue)) 
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I even removed all code from `Convert()` method and put `return null;` there. Didn't work either

Comment: Try using DependencyProperty.UnsetValue for Convert and ConvertBack instead of null.